# How do I remove a component in RTC

Tags: version-control

Under "My Repository Workspaces > Components" I have several components that I want to remove. I am the owner but I don't have any option to delete them.

I have no workspaces created either.

How do I delete these components? I'm using RTC Client 2.0.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.

You can hide it (by changing its ownership) or you can rename it and reuse it.

But you can't delete it.

There is a [Work Item for requesting that feature (Story 163568)](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=163568).
But don't hold your breath.